# Is it possible to have a different template for pagination?

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm wanting to have my list of entries be formatted differently on the first page. But I can't figure out if there's any way to check which page is being shown.

I'm able to get my posts and have them paginated, but I can't find information on how to do something like this (or if it's even possible or not)

```
{% if record.number == 1 %}
    first page template
{% else %}
    other pages
{% endif %}
```

Or possibly set another twig file as for the other layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `app.request` to get the GET parameter which contains the page number. Then you can check if you are on the first page or not.